# Можно ли в EntityFramework Core 2.0 сделать отображение в Dictionary

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Я пишу

```
public class A {
   ...
   public List<B> Bs { get;set;} 
}
```

а можно ли сделать что-то типа такого?

```
public class A {
   ...
   public Dictionary<int,B> Bs { get;set;} // int - B Id
}
```

Comment: А что будет выступать в качестве ключа?

Comment: @Андрей Id, или какое-то другое индексное поле, которое я укажу

Comment: А смысл? Быстрей это работать все равно не будет, а искать запись по id вы и так можете с помощью `Find` или `First`

Comment: @Андрей ну как я знаю по листу поиск идёт за N операций где N размер листа, а по словарю за константу. Поэтому и хочется использовать словарь. Это, конечно, в случае если записи уже подгружены. А мне именно такая ситуация и важна.

Comment: В том-то и дело, что если записи уже подгружены. Делайте отдельный Dictionary, который ни на что не отображается в БД, загружайте данные из БД и помещайте в него вручную

Comment: @Андрей Ну наверное так делать и буду, если в EF напрямую это делать нельзя.. Но вопрос тем не менее остаётся.